# How to make start menu search look for searched item throughout the entire system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

Start menu search option only searches the `C:\` drive. I want it to search the entire computer (all drives), how do I do this in Windows 10?

Comment: Searching the whole drive might work for a small system, but for a big system, it could take a lot of time because system files are not indexed. Better in most cases to index what you need (nominally Users and Outlook) and use that as the default search. In Windows Explorer, you can go to the top right of any folder and search that whole folder and its children.

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to learn that the search didn't do this already!

To fix this go to search for something, then click on the three dots in the top right of the search screen.

[image: Screenshot of the Windows 10 startmenu search]

Next click on "Indexing options".

Then select "Enchanced" under the "Find My Files" heading. Please note that this might take a VERY long time if you have a lot of files on other drives.

[image: Screenshot of the indexing options settings screen with the enhanced option selected]